# Making images interactive and swappable using php, mysql and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Grateful for any help on this. I'm very new to all this stuff.

I've created a jquery 'live search' form that links the input characters of a form to associated images of letter artwork in my mysql database (e.g., user enters f-l-o-w-e-r in live search and php echos six images).

Here's the php code for reference, which passes the images to a div in index.php:

```
foreach(str_split($_POST['search_term']) as $alpha) 
        { 
        echo "<img src='../delete/images/{$alpharray[$alpha][0]['imagePath']}' width='100' height='140'></src></a>"; 
        }
```

I'd like a user to click on one of these images to open a carousel of related images from which s/he could drag and drop a new image to swap out the old one. Eventually they could submit the entire self-selected array of letters as an order.

From the jquery side, I can figure out the carousel and how to make something draggable, droppable. But I'm having trouble mentally mapping how I do the swappable part. Make a new array? Maybe someone can help set me straight with some hints...?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Frankly, this is a request for idiot-proof guidance to set a novice on the track for researching this better. As I understand it, I'm sequentially echoing particular values of an array. This is a static output.

TO make it dynamic, do I (for example) instead need to create a new array from these values and pass this array to jquery? then do I use something like .replacewith() in jquery to enable the user to dynamically interact with and change this array?  That approach is probably wrong. It's clarifying this part that I need help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what exactly your problem is, but you could read the sources of the images which an .each() and post them to your php script. As it seems there you have an array which holds all the data, and you just read the elements you want. So you could just overwrite the elements that you want to change, or create a new array, depending on what exactly you want to do. And also you tagged your question mysql, not quite sure how your data is stored.

Edit:

---

Alright, I see two possible ways here. One would be creating all the images to each image in a div right on creation like this:

```
foreach(str_split($_POST['search_term']) as $alpha) 
{ 
    echo "<img class="clickable" src='../delete/images/{$alpharray[$alpha][0]['imagePath']}' width='100' height='140'></src></a>"; 
    echo '<div class="editimages">';
    // Code that creates the images with which the above image can be replaced
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Downside is, that the user gets all the images at the same time which might be loading slow and creating alot of traffic. Upside is, that it the easiest solution, and will react fast when the user clicks. You could just do something like

```
$(".clickable").click(function(){
    $(".editimages").hide();
    $(this).next().show();
});
```

In your JS.

---

The other solution would be loading the images on click, at the moment the user wants to edit one. Upside is, that it will only load the images you need and so save  traffic and load faster on init, but it will start to get the replacement images when the user wants to see them, so depending on how fast the server is and how big the images are, this might feel a bit slower.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I understand what the .each() does, but I'm not sure I'm following you. I tried to add clarification in comments above. Eventually I might have hundreds of images. The mysql table has attributes for the images, one of which is the pathway to images stored in a folder. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. That's good food for thought. I'll see where I can take it. My goal is to make it so that only the 'portfolio' of a particular letter clicked (e.g. the h portfolio in the inputted word h-o-n-e-y) would be called out on click. I'm probably reading your script wrong, but it seems your way would call out the same aggregate portfolio no matter which letter was clicked. I may need a new php query to be fired onclick or something like what you suggest in the second option.

Comment: what it would do is: if you click on a image, then the div right after it will be shown. So you have one for each letter which is created in your foreach above. You only have to create them in the line with the comment before.

Comment: Of course! Thanks! I think that'll work great. I've created some nested foreach to flatten the array and echo out all the images from the query. I'm having trouble figuring out how to select only for the inputted character and not the all the queried rows, but I think that's a different question. Thanks again.